# Taking out extra pipes in Visual Basic code for excel file macro

Tags: excel, vba

I have created an excel file that has a macro that does multiple things. In the image, you can see how to excel file looks. The user will enter their data on rows 12 and 13. The macro will run and it will create a notepad file that uses pipe delimiters. As you can see, it creates extra pipes on the first row of the text - that's what I am trying to get rid of.

[image: Excel File Snip]

[image: Current Output]

[image: Needed Output]

```
    Sub NewPipeFile()

    Dim IntialName As String
    Dim sFileSaveName As Variant
    IntialName = "Sample Output"
    sFileSaveName = Application.GetSaveAsFilename(InitialFileName:=InitialName, fileFilter:="Excel Files (*.xlsm), *.xlsm")

    If sFileSaveName <> False Then
        ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs sFileSaveName
    End If

    'Deletes instructions
    Rows("1:11").Select
    Range("A11").Activate
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp

    'Deletes bottom 85 rows so end up with no blank lines
    Rows("14:14").Select
    ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=90
    Rows("14:100").Select
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp

    'Deletes comments, makes text black, etc
    Selection.Font.Bold = False
    With Selection.Font
        .ColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .TintAndShade = 0
    End With
    Selection.ClearComments



Const myDelim As String = "|"
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = ActiveSheet
Dim r As Long, c As Long, i As Long, j As Long
r = ws.Cells.Find(What:="*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row
c = ws.Cells.Find(What:="*", SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Column
Dim myPath As String
myPath = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\"
Dim myFile As String
myFile = myPath & Format(Now(), "yyyy-mm-dd--hh-mm-ss") & "PipeFile.txt"
Dim obj As Object
Set obj = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
obj.Type = 2
obj.Charset = "unicode"
obj.Open
Dim v() As Variant
ReDim v(1 To c)
For i = 1 To r
For j = 1 To c
v(j) = ws.Cells(i, j).Text
Next
obj.WriteText Join(v, myDelim), 1
Next
obj.SaveToFile myFile, 2
Dim Npad
Npad = Shell("C:\WINDOWS\notepad.exe " & myFile, 1)
End Sub
```

Comment: You're going to need to go back through and have a check completed to see if "|" is next to another "|" and if it is, replace with " ".

Comment: Or just check the cell isn't empty before adding to the array.

Comment: Don't use a 2D array and recalculate c for each row. By the way, it is not usually done like you did.

Comment: And if you don't care about the .Text format, you can directly assign range to arrays

Comment: there's a much easier way to do this, but the question I have is will there ever be cases where there are blank cells in between data points?

Comment: I don't care about the cleanliness of it, I just need it to work. I've tried deleting all text/characters in those cells (E12-Q12) too in the macro and it didn't work.

Comment: And why using a ADODB.Stream to write a simple text file?

Comment: I think there are much better ways of doing what you are doing. But if you have that in a string, you could just have a `DO` loop (`Do While InStr(1, myStr, "||") > 0`). Then have the following in your loop: `myStr = Replace(myStr, "||", "|")`.. where `myStr` is the variable that holds your string

Comment: @ScottHoltzman Yeah, it's an EDI file so there may be a DATA|Data1||Data3|Data4||Data6  etc on row 13

Answer (score 0):

Loop like this:

```
For i = 1 To r
  c = ws.Cells(r,ws.columns.count).end(xlToLeft).column
  Dim v as Variant
  v = ws.Range(ws.Cells(r,1),ws.Cells(r,c)).Value
  objWriteText Join(WorksheetFunction.Transpose(WorksheetFunction.Transpose(v)), myDelim), 1
Next
```

I am using transpose here as the column list is relatively few columns (so won't affect speed). I use it twice because it's column based. So first transpose is to get it row based and 2nd is to make it 1D since range's default to 2D arrays.